# Telerik MVC Grid paging error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework-4.1, telerik-mvc

I'm using the telerik mvc grid which shows up fine with the proper css classes applied and has data in it but the paging doesn't seem to work... When I click on the one of the page numbers at the bottom of the grid it throws this error:

The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip'

I realized that I didn't have the scripts registered so I put them in:

```
@Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar.DefaultGroup(Sub(groups)
                     groups.Add("~/Scripts/2011.2.712/telerik.common.min.js")
                     groups.Add("~/Scripts/2011.2.712/telerik.grid.min.js")
                                                 End Sub)
```

Also tried:

```
@Html.telerik().ScriptRegistrar()
```

When it tries to register these scripts it complains that it cannont find telerik.common.js.  I looked in the telerik folder (program files) where I got the script files originally and there is no telerik.common.js only the min version of it...

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is your database? Is it SQL Server or something else? (Access?). The error you mentioned is about your database/data not your script files. Script registeration is done automatically by Telerik().ScriptRegister method. you don't need to do it manually (except in rare ajax cases).

Comment: It's SQL Server.  I am using AJAX as well.

Comment: Do you still have the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add it this way (without .min. )

group.Add("telerik.common.js").

Telerik ScriptRegistrar automatically converts it to "telerik.common.min.js"